# How to get gvedit (GVEdit Graph File Editor) for Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, package-management, software-installation, 18.10

There is a link on official [GraphViz documentation page](http://graphviz.org/documentation/) to the [man-page](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/pdf/gvedit.1.pdf) of `gvedit` utility:

> **NAME**
>   `gvedit` − simple graph editor and viewer

But what is interesting - this utility is [not included in official Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gvedit).

I reported [bug 1784224 to launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/graphviz/+bug/1784224) about missed executable.

How to get gvedit (GVEdit Graph File Editor) for Ubuntu?

Comment: Going by the date of the manpage, gvedit seems to long abandoned. Does it even build on modern systems?

Comment: @muru See answer below. It compiles normally (tested on 16.04 LTS). Very strange issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by [`debian/control` file](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/graphviz/tree/debian/control?h=ubuntu/xenial-updates&id=eb433107ef465d83528829dc4a58aaeac2297217) - it does not contain build-dependency for GUI - Qt.

Compiling package on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS or 18.04.2 LTS system from source installs `gvedit` executable to it.

We need, at first, to enable *source code* repositories, in Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`), and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts libqt4-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep graphviz

cd ~/Downloads
apt-get source --build graphviz
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
```

As a result, `gvedit` files are in place and registered in APT-database:

```
$ dpkg -S gvedit
graphviz: /usr/share/man/man1/gvedit.1.gz
graphviz-doc: /usr/share/doc/graphviz/pdf/gvedit.1.pdf
graphviz: /usr/bin/gvedit
```

The GVEdit application seems to work normally:

[image: GVEdit window on 16.04 LTS]

But shows error in the terminal:

> ```
> Could not open attribute name file "/usr/share/graphviz/gvedit/attrs.txt" for reading
> ```

We can fix this problem by copying this file from source package:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/graphviz/gvedit/
cd ~/Downloads
sudo cp graphviz-*/doc/infosrc/attrs /usr/share/graphviz/gvedit/attrs.txt
```

We need to pin self-compiled packages to prevent their upgrade (and the loss of `gvedit`):

```
sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-gv >/dev/null <<EOF
Package: graphviz
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: graphviz-dev
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: graphviz-doc
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libcdt5
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libcgraph6
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgraphviz-dev
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgvc6
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgvc6-plugins-gtk
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgv-guile
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgv-lua
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgv-perl
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgvpr2
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgv-python
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgv-ruby
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgv-tcl
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libpathplan4
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libxdot4
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

# for 18.04 LTS
Package: libgv-php7
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: liblab-gamut1
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: python3-gv
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: python-gv
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1337

EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

this is to supplement @magjac's answer. I recognise this answer is for Ubuntu 20, but I've posted it here because this is the only thread I found about gvedit on Ubuntu and it should be applicable to Ubuntu 18.

Here are my installation steps:

```
#dependancy installation
sudo apt install freeglut3 libglade2-0 libgtkglext1 libpangox-1.0-0 libdevil1c2 liblasi0 libpoppler-glib8 liballegro4.4

wget https://www2.graphviz.org/Packages/stable/ubuntu/20.04/os/x86_64/libgraphviz4_2.44.1-1_amd64.deb
wget https://www2.graphviz.org/Packages/stable/ubuntu/20.04/os/x86_64/graphviz_2.44.1-1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libgraphviz4_2.44.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i graphviz_2.44.1-1_amd64.deb
```

Obviously version numbers will vary with time and your dependencies may be different than mine.

It may also be possible to use `sudo apt -f install` to get the dependencies as per the answer here: https://linuxhint.com/install_deb_file_ubuntu/

Comment: Inspiration for what dependencies that might be needed might be possible to obtain from https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/blob/master/ci/ubuntu-20.04/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Graphviz releases containing `gvedit` are available at https://www2.graphviz.org/Packages/stable/ubuntu/.

Comment: It is great, but it is not installable on 16.04 LTS.

Comment: We had plans to build Graphviz for Ubuntu 16.04 as well, but had to give it up due to lack of Debian knowledge. See https://forum.graphviz.org/t/building-for-ubuntu-16-04-lts-in-ci/167

Comment: Your forum link is dead.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Try again. I just made it available for everyone. It was restricted before.